Is there a way to plot specific chromosome regions with cytobands in R using hg38?
I am trying to plot a certain region of chromosome 16 with respective chromosome bands and genes in the area. I played with ggbio, however, it doesn't seem to accept hg38 as reference genome. Is there another way to plot this information?
library(ggbio)
plotIdeogram(genome = "hg38")

gives me an Error message:
> [1] "hg38"
Loading ideogram...
Error in normArgTrack(track, trackids) : Unknown track: cytoBand
In addition: Warning message:
In .local(x, ...) :
  'track' parameter is deprecated now you go by the 'table' instead
                Use ucscTables(genome, track) to retrieve the list of tables for a track
cytoBand informatin is not available, only get ranges.
Loading ranges...
Done
use chr1 automatically

It then plots an empty bar. Any help is appreciated!
